# Unable to create secure site not running on port 443

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

So I am using the Gitlab registry helm chart, for legacy support I have to expose the registry at example.com:4567.

I am able to expose the port but unable to create a secure connection. E.g. chrome states "This site can't provide a secure connection"

Any advice would be appreciated.

wget logs:

```
wget https://example.com:4567/
--2020-02-20 08:39:23--  https://example.com:4567/
Resolving example.com (example.com)... .............
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|...........|:4567... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

nginx-ingress helm chart relevant config:

```
tcp:
  4567: "gitlab/gitlab-registry:5000"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    flux.weave.works/antecedent: gitlab:helmrelease/gitlab
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-18T08:44:54Z"
  labels:
    app: registry
    chart: registry-0.3.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: gitlab
  name: gitlab-registry
  namespace: gitlab
  resourceVersion: "882239"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/gitlab/services/gitlab-registry
  uid: 43d97af6-656f-44ae-a064-cae1bfb37524
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.101.88.115
  ports:
  - name: registry
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: registry
    release: gitlab
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Gitlab helm chart:

```
global:
  appconfig:
    registry:
      ingress:
        tls:
          enabled: true
          secretName: gitlab-sdp-tls
```

The secret above works perfectly for example.com

```
curl -vvv https://example.com:4567

* Rebuilt URL to: example.com:4567/ 
* Trying xxxxxxxxxx... 
* Connected to example.com (xxxxxxxxxxxxx) port 4567 (#0) 
> GET / HTTP/1.1 
> Host: example.com:4567 
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0 
> Accept: */* 
> 
* Empty reply from server 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: could you run `curl -vvv https://example.com:4567` ?

Comment: ```* Rebuilt URL to: example.com:4567/
*   Trying xxxxxxxxxx...
* Connected to example.com (xxxxxxxxxxxxx) port 4567 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com:4567
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server```

Comment: I will also mention that example.com is a CNAME pointing towards the actual DNS "ugly.example.com"

Comment: What makes you think it's the port? Have you tried it on 443?

Comment: Yes, using default settings, port 443 and certificate this works perfectly.

Comment: So , just to recap. Am I right that for the port 443 both wget and curl works fine and for 4567 only curl works, but not wget ? What is the OS version on machine you are running curl/wget from and what is the output of `wget --version` ?